# Why does my picture get cropped when viewing it on LCD screen?

Tags: digital, canon-600d, lcd

I have a canon T3i, and when I look through the viewfinder and take a picture, the picture comes out fine. However, if I try to take a picture through the LCD screen, the screen shows two blue lines and when i take the picture, it gets cropped on those lines. Anyone knows what settings to change to avoid this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's on page 129 of the [EOS Rebel T3i/600D Instruction Manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0300004720/02/eosrt3i-eos600d-im2-c-en.pdf)

[image: p.129]

It appears your camera is currently set to 16:9. To do what you want, you need to set it to 3:2.